# javascript json parsing query with mongodb

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb

I have a function which gets data from my mongodb database. I am trying to console log the result. I can see the result as

```
console.log(result);
```

This gives

```
[
  {
    _id: 5f2940b77e6f8b26e0726cb9,
    Val_String: '2',
    T1_String: '2162',
    T2_String: '2068',
    T3_String: '1950',
    T4_String: '1956',
    Pdiff_String: '-0.010000',
    Time_String: '2020-05-20 12:51:20 GMT',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

However, when I do:

```
var T1 = result.T1_String;
console.log(T1);
```

I get undefined. So my question is how do I correctly parse this to get my data.

Comment: write result[0].T1_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to access the first object in the list. Therefore

```
var T1 = result[0].T1_String;
console.log(T1);
```

will give the t1 string

Answer (score 1):

The result gives back an array of objects and not just a single object.
Access the objects by square bracket notation `[]`

```
var T1 = result[0].T1_String; //result[0] is the first object in the array
```